# PHP database class does not commit

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a php class what is able to handle my query's and db connections.

I've played around with it for a while and did some research, now I've created m When I use the class for something to handle it does not commit, but I'm not able to see why it doesn't
I don't get any error's and my mysqli error handling is correct.

does anyone have a idea what's wrong with my script?

sql class:

```
class sql{

    function convertArrayReferences($arr){
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;
    }
    function database($database, $query, $parameters){
        $result;
        $mysqli = new mysqli("****", "****", "****", $database);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            return "Connect failed: %s\n " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        if(!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
            return $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_param($this->convertArrayReferences($parameters))){
            return $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_result($result)){
            return $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            return $mysqli->error;
        }

        $stmt->close();

        return $mysqli->error;
    }  
}
```

the bit of code where the function is called:

```
$execute = $sql->database("survivalTmpReg",
"INSERT INTO USERS (name, surname, email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
array("sssss", $name, $surname, $email, $username, $password));

if($execute){
    $message = REGISTER_MESSAGE;
}else{
    $message = $execute;
}
```

Comment: What SQL command are you executing?

Comment: This one:
INSERT INTO USERS (name, surname, email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) @antiguru

Comment: Well, that statement does not commit. Unless you have autocommit turned on, it should never materialize in your database until you explicitly commit.

Comment: doesn't $stmt->execute() do that? @antiguru

Answer (score 0):

Statements are not automatically committed unless autocommit is turned on. On the first statement a transaction is created. Unless the transaction is not explicitly committed its changes will not be visible and eventually the transaction will be aborted by the system. MySQLi supports committing transactions using [mysqli::commit](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've turned autocommit to true and I've inserted the mysqli->commit but is still doesn't work, no errors nothing...